# How can I set PHP cookie with JavaScript in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I want to set a PHP cookie through a button click event of JavaScript how can I achieve this. Is there any big minds can help me.

```
<script>
    function openC(){
        <?php setcookie('z', 'on', time() + (86000), "/" ); ?>
        oopen();
    }
</script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 p-rel">
            <button type="button" onclick="openC()" id="opner" class="btn hide btn-dark "><i
                    class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

above is my code if I try to echo my cookie in another page like my header page I get nothing

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!--Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" href="<?= base_url() ?>assets/new_assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">

        <link href="<?= base_url() ?>assets/new_assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <!--Site Title-->
        <title><?php echo!empty($title) ? $title : ""; ?></title>
        <p> <?php echo $_COOKIE["z"]; ?></p>
    </head>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
    </script>
```

Comment: thats not how backend and frontend work...

Comment: Can you please say `WHY` you need to do that?

Comment: I want to include and hide a sidebar on the bases of this cookie value

Comment: Ifaruki Then tell me how can I achieve this